# How can find image type without extension in php?

Tags: php

I have image upload php class. This process uploaded Images(.png,jpeg,.gif).
             I am using this function to find image type

```
 function getImageType($image_name){
    return end(explode('.',$mage_name));
              }
```

if someone upload any file with fake extension . error will happen. How can i Check type of image without
            checking extension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to get the mime type, and switch on the type to create generate extension.

In code this could look like something like this:

```
$image_info = getImageSize($path);
switch ($image_info['mime']) {
case 'image/gif':
    $extension = '.gif';
    break;
case 'image/jpeg':
    $extension = '.jpg';
    break;
case 'image/png':        
    $extension = '.png';
    break;
default:
    // handle errors
    break;
}
```

Comment: this might work as well: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Function names in PHP are case-sensitive. `getImageSize()` does not exist, unless you create it first.

Comment: @XedinUnknown as far as i know they are [case **in**-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) it says (in a note somewhere in the middle): "Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration."

Comment: I lived in a lie my whole life... The whole language is CS, and function names are CI.....